# NGINX reverse proxy adding 'undefined' to request path (docker, node, create-react-app)

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, react-router, create-react-app

I am running a basic NGINX configuration on localhost:80. It serves static files (create-react-app's build folder) from "/". It proxies all requests with /api to localhost:8000 (where the node server is running).

I am using docker-compose + Dockerfiles to spin up the node (express) server and the NGINX server.

**ALSO: I am using react-router which I am aware can cause conflicts with requests**

It is my understanding that docker-compose automatically creates a network for the containers it manages, so I don't need to create one manually.

Once both of the containers are up and running and I navigate to the browser @ localhost:80, it shows my landing page for a split second before going blank. The error messages that I get are:

`apiPost.js:22 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

and

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

This leads me to believe that I have something wrong with my NGINX setup, since the request is returning the index.html page in my build folder rather than the JSON response from my node server. Upon inspecting the request in the network tab on Chrome, I see that it is making a GET request to `http://localhost/undefined/posts`. After researching what could be going wrong, I can't seem to figure out why the requests are being prefixed with 'undefined' (since I believe this is why the requests are not being proxied to my node server).

Here is the docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:

  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: node-server
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./server/.env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"


  public:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./public
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on: 
      - server
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./server/.env
```

Here are the respective Dockerfiles:

```
FROM node:alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /public

COPY . .

RUN npm i && npm run build



FROM nginx:alpine

COPY /nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY --from=builder /public/build /home

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

```
FROM node:12.16.1-alpine

WORKDIR /api

COPY . .

RUN apk add --no-cache make gcc g++ python && \
  npm install && \
  npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source && \
  apk del make gcc g++ python

USER node

CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

Here is the .env variable that is setting the url for requests:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL="http://localhost:8000/api"
```

(I have also tried different urls here, such as `localhost:80`, `localhost:8000` (without/api), and `/api`)

Here is the request that is being fired off:

```
export const list = () => {
    return fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/posts`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
    })
    .then(res => {return res.json()})
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

And last but not least, here is the NGINX config in question:

```
server {

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  root /home;
  index index.html;

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/api;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
  
}
```

If anyone can help me with this, it would be superrrrr appreciated :)

Comment: Can you please share contents of ./server/.env file? My guess is value for `REACT_APP_API_URL` is not being resolved for UI code and therefore ```fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/posts``` is being replaced by ```fetch(`undefined/posts```.

Comment: Try replacing ```proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/api;``` with ```proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/api/;```

Basically adding slash at the end of ```8000/api/```

Comment: Im facing the same issue, is there any solution for this ? adding "/" did not work for me.